# Warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class

Tags: android

I download a video call app from this [link](https://github.com/3bytessolutions/CallService-sample) on github , I open the project in android studio and there is no build errors , but when i run the project this error appear and i tried many times to solve it with different ways but i can't solve it.

This is the error : [Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAPTW.png)

I appreciate any help , thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have you original installer?

Comment: Uninstall your current version and download an older version from the [archives](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive).